# Are these functions on a Hilbert space Lipschitz equivalent?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space with inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$. Fix a bounded operator $T$ on $H$, and $1\leq p<\infty$ (you can assume $p$ is an integer if necessary). Consider the following maps:

$$H\to[0,\infty):x\mapsto|\langle Tx,x\rangle|^p$$

and

$$H\to[0,\infty):x\mapsto\langle |T|^px,x\rangle.$$

Are these maps Lipschitz equivalent? That is, do there exist constants $c,C>0$ such that
$$c|\langle Tx,x\rangle|^p\leq \langle |T|^px,x\rangle\leq C|\langle Tx,x\rangle|^p$$
for all $x\in H$? If not, are there any such inequalities between these quantities?

Comment: By $\lvert T \rvert$ do you mean the norm of $T$? Sorry, I've just never seen this notation before.

Comment: I mean the absolute value of $T$, that is, the unique positive bounded operator satisfying $\|Tx\|=\||T|x\|$ for all $x\in H$. It can be defined by $|T|=(T^*T)^{1/2}$.

Comment: Ah thanks, learn something new every time I come on here :D

Comment: If $T$ is rotation by $90$ degrees in the plane, then $|T|$ is the identity map, and the right half of your conjectured inequality fails.

Comment: I see, and a similar example works for an infinite dimensional $H$, and compact $T$ (my original interest): Fix an orthonormal basis $\{e_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ for $H$, and let $T(e_0)=e_1$, and $T(e_n)=0$ for $n>0$. Then $|T|$ is the projection onto the span of $e_0$. But $\langle|T|^pe_0,e_0\rangle=1$, while $\langle Te_0,e_0\rangle=0$.